# "Initialising" is to "initialisation" as "enabling" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a valid word for the act of enabling?

I want to say "[enablement](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enable)". It is listed in the dictionary, but is it in common use? I've never heard it before. Is there a more apt word?

Comment: Enabling is what you do when you enable something, so *enabling* is the act. What do you mean by the act of enabling?

Comment: @Matt I've changed the title now. I hope that clarifies my question. Having said that, your answer may actually be correct.

Comment: Your parsing of the dictionary entry is erroneous. Enablement is not specific to electronics.

Comment: @Matt I see what you mean. I've changed the question to reflect this. Re-open please!

Comment: Now your question is reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Enablement" is the noun form of the verb *enable*. [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, 1913 Edition](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/WEBSTER.sh?WORD=enablement) defines it as follows:

> The act of enabling, or the state of being enabled; ability.

Other dictionaries defining this term are:

- [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/enablement)
- [Online Plain Text English Dictionary](http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/v003/wb1913_e.html)
- [Webster's 1828 Dictionary](http://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/enablement)
- [Babylon Online](http://online.babylon.com/combo/index.html?word=enablement&lang=0&type=3)

Comment: I see. You're right. I've altered my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

‘Enablement’, in the sense of ‘the action or means of enabling’ is well attested in the OED from 1495 onwards.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Urbycoz: "in the OED" is his reference, "OED" is the Oxford English Dictionary. (see [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/147/list-of-common-abbreviations-noad-esl-pie) for more abbreviations)

Comment: That's not what I meant. It's not a reference that can be easily checked. Barrie, is there a link you can give to back up your claim?

Comment: @Urbycoz: Sorry, I’ve only just noticed that I hadn’t replied. The 1495 citation is from an Act of Parliament and reads: ‘This acte of enhablement and restitucion of Thomas Erle of Surrey.’

Answer (score 1):

[Facilitation](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/facilitation#facilitate__3), perhaps?

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U, Ratz. Adding a dictionary link or a conjecture about why your suggestion is suitable (for a single-word-request) will usually suffice if you need more text to meet the minimum answer length, and it helps to make your answer more useful.

Answer (score 1):

*Empowering* may be suitable in certain contexts.

> He believed in empowering (enabling) his followers.

Here is the Google dictionary result (second one on the list may be of interest to you):

> empowering is a form of:
>   em·pow·er
>
> verb /emˈpou(-ə)r/ 
>   empowered, past participle; empowered, past tense; empowering, present participle; empowers, 3rd person singular present
>
> Give (someone) the authority or power to do something
>          - nobody was empowered to sign checks on her behalf
>
> Enable (someone) to do (something)
>          - cryptography will empower individuals to control their information
>
> Make (someone) stronger and more confident, esp. in controlling their life and claiming their rights
>          - movements to empower the poor

Comment: Also, in the negative sense, allowing someone like an alcoholic to continue their destructive behavior. [see also](http://alcoholism.about.com/cs/info2/a/aa052197.htm)